# What is the difference between web.xml error 500 and struts global exception?

Tags: java, exception, struts, web.xml

For handling errors in my java web application, I can use:

- In the web.xml file define `<error-page>` like so:

  ```
  <error-page>
      <error-code>500</error-code>
      <location>/file_not_found.html</location>
  </error-page>
  ```
- Or in struts-config.xml define the `<global-exceptions>` like so:

  ```
  <global-exceptions>
      <exception
        key="error.global.mesage"
        type="java.lang.Exception"
        path="/pages/error.jsp" />
  </global-exceptions>
  ```

What is the difference?

In which cases should I use each of these options?

What would happen if both are defined in the same application? (Does it make sense to define both?)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a sample project, with simple servlets/jsps directly serving some simple content(static files, statistics, etc), and a more complex Struts based app serving a business portal.

Uncaught exceptions thrown in simple servlets/jsps, the exception information will be displayed as you defined in your **web.xml**'s "error-page" directives, not Strut's.

Uncaught exceptions thrown in Struts based business portal, the exception information will be displayed as you defined in your **struts-config.xml**'s "global-exceptions" directives.

For more clearance, in rare cases, but not impossible, a bug in Struts framework itself throws an exception, it can only be caught by application server/servlet container and displayed using **web.xml**'s "error-page" directives.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a container-level error page specifically for 500s (internal server errors).

The second is a framework-level error page specifically for all `Exception` subclasses thrown during the exception interceptor's action invocation.

It's possible that there could be an exception before/after the exception interceptor: this means you likely *should* declare both, assuming it meets your requirements.

I prefer to handle app-specific exceptions as close to the app as possible: this means that using Struts 2's declarative exception handling mechanisms is my choice for anything inside the application itself. It can happen that the framework itself, or even the container, could throw an exception before (or after) the framework has done the bulk of its processing, however.